# What's the best way to handle errors/timeout when loading an iframe with jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, timeout

I'm loading an iframe by changing its src attribute and then registering a handler for its load event, i.e.

obj.iframe.attr('src', src);
obj.iframe.load(function() {
...
});

This works well as long as the iframe loads correctly.  I'm wondering if there's an easy way using jquery to set a timeout for the iframe to load and detect errors if it doesn't load correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could put in the load function of the iframe a function which set a variable to true, and then use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to check regularly if all is going ok. When the iframe is loaded correctly, you can use `clearInterval` to stop the checking operation.